# MEME-Generator (jQuery and CSS Help)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to create a very basic meme generator to practice some basic jQuery and have run into a little problem.

Here's the basics of how I set it up to work...for now.

1.) There are three sample images you can click that will populate inside of the div with id, "meme" at the top of the page when clicked.
2.) The User can use the two input forms I created to place top text, and bottom text.

Everything works in regards to that, but I believe the problem I am facing is more CSS related, but I am not too sure, as I am a beginner with jQuery.

The problem I am speaking of, is that inside the col-sm-6 where the meme image and  top text and bottom text sit, the text that the user can type will keep going and break out of the col-sm-6 container and keep going.

However, I was able to stop that by setting, overflow: hidden, within each text section in the css, but the text still spans the full-with of the col-sm-6 container, which is larger than the actual image.

My main goal would be for the text to wrap when it hits the borders of the image, and not the actual outside col-sm-6 container. I know I am using bootstrap, so the column's won't work here, but if you use the meme gen in the results window, it works, and you can still see that the text overflows past the size of the image.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#meme-controls').on('keyup','#top-text-input', function() {
      $('#top-text').text($(this).val());
  });
  $('#meme-controls').on('keyup','#btm-text-input', function() {
      $('#btm-text').text($(this).val());
  });
  $('#meme-samples').on('click','img', function() {
    $('#meme').empty().append($(this).data('src'));
  });
});
```

```css
#meme {
  position: relative;
}

#meme-samples {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#top-text {
  top: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#btm-text {
  bottom: 10px;;
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!-- MEME Display -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div id="meme"></div>
      <h2 id="top-text"></h2>
      <h2 id="btm-text"></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- MEME Controls -->
<div id="meme-controls" class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" id="top-text-input" class="form-control" placeholder="Top Text Goes Here."><br>
    <input type="text" id="btm-text-input" class="form-control" placeholder="Bottom Text Goes Here."><br>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- MEME Sample Photos-->
<div id="meme-samples" class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://makeameme.org/media/templates/250/willy_wonka_sarcasm_meme.jpg" data-src="<img src='https://makeameme.org/media/templates/250/willy_wonka_sarcasm_meme.jpg'>">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://makeameme.org/media/templates/250/game_of_thrones_meme.jpg" data-src="<img src='https://makeameme.org/media/templates/250/game_of_thrones_meme.jpg'>">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://makeameme.org/media/templates/250/the_most_interesting_man_in_the_world.jpg" data-src="<img src='https://makeameme.org/media/templates/250/the_most_interesting_man_in_the_world.jpg'>">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Ty for the response, I'll have a look at this later today and comment back if it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the image and text in `#meme`, collapse that with `display: inline-block` (you could also use `float` or other methods depending on situation). The text won't expand greater than the width of `#meme` which will only be as big as the image.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#meme-controls').on('keyup','#top-text-input', function() {
      $('#top-text').text($(this).val());
  });
  $('#meme-controls').on('keyup','#btm-text-input', function() {
      $('#btm-text').text($(this).val());
  });
  $('#meme-samples').on('click','img', function() {
    $('#meme-image').attr('src', $(this).attr('src')); /* use selected image's src */
    $('#meme-image').show();
  });
});
```

```css
#meme {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block; /* collapse container */
}

#meme-samples {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#top-text {
  top: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#btm-text {
  bottom: 10px;;
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!-- MEME Display -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div id="meme"> <!-- use #meme to contain image and text -->
        <h2 id="top-text"></h2>
        <h2 id="btm-text"></h2>
        <img id="meme-image" style="display: none;" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- MEME Controls -->
<div id="meme-controls" class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" id="top-text-input" class="form-control" placeholder="Top Text Goes Here."><br>
    <input type="text" id="btm-text-input" class="form-control" placeholder="Bottom Text Goes Here."><br>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- MEME Sample Photos-->
<div id="meme-samples" class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://makeameme.org/media/templates/250/willy_wonka_sarcasm_meme.jpg" data-src="<img src='https://makeameme.org/media/templates/250/willy_wonka_sarcasm_meme.jpg'>">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://makeameme.org/media/templates/250/game_of_thrones_meme.jpg" data-src="<img src='https://makeameme.org/media/templates/250/game_of_thrones_meme.jpg'>">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://makeameme.org/media/templates/250/the_most_interesting_man_in_the_world.jpg" data-src="<img src='https://makeameme.org/media/templates/250/the_most_interesting_man_in_the_world.jpg'>">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You sir win the golden ticket. May the jQuery odd's forever be in your favor! Thanks a lot for the help that was a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Give `<canvas>` a try. See it in action: http://codepen.io/johano/pen/emNRmb
You can easily convert a `<canvas>` element into a base64 image string and save it as image. You don´t need jQuery. Just pure vanillaJs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.